# Is 'adapt to [infinitive]' generally used?

Tags: usage

Is ***to adapt to [infinitive]*** generally used in addition to ***to adapt to [-ing]*** form?  If so, is there any difference in meaning, like using ***to [infinitive]*** to express a purpose or intention or something like that?

> This confusion occurred because his brain hadn’t yet learned to see.
> Though we often tend to assume our eyes function as video cameras
> which relay information to our brain, advances in neuroscientific
> research have proven that this is actually not the case. Instead,
> sight is a collaborative effort between our eyes and our brains, and
> the way we process visual reality depends on the way these two
> communicate. If communication between our eyes and our brains is
> disturbed, our perception of reality is altered accordingly. And
> because other areas of May’s brain ***had adapted to process***
> information primarily through his other senses, the process of
> learning how to see was more difficult than he’d anticipated.

[Summary of The Brain by David Eagleman](https://books.google.co.kr/books?id=tP_LDwAAQBAJ&pg=PP8&lpg=PP8&dq=After%20he%E2%80%99d%20learned%20to%20know%20his%20family%20through%20touch%20and%20smell,%20he%20found%20that%20he%20couldn%E2%80%99t%20recognize%20his%20children%20with%20his%20eyes,%20and%20this%20left%20him%20puzzled.%20Skiing%20also%20became%20a%20lot%20harder%20as%20he%20struggled%20to%20adapt%20to%20the%20visual%20stimulation.&source=bl&ots=fHRzGl1l1A&sig=ACfU3U0wh8nqag8PEwn7jTtjj-NvQf47jg&hl=en&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwjU1_3h7eOCAxU8mlYBHZL0DMMQ6AF6BAgQEAM#v=onepage&q=After%20he%E2%80%99d%20learned%20to%20know%20his%20family%20through%20touch%20and%20smell%2C%20he%20found%20that%20he%20couldn%E2%80%99t%20recognize%20his%20children%20with%20his%20eyes%2C%20and%20this%20left%20him%20puzzled.%20Skiing%20also%20became%20a%20lot%20harder%20as%20he%20struggled%20to%20adapt%20to%20the%20visual%20stimulation.&f=false)

Comment: The key difference here is the word "to." "Adapt to" is a phrase, but "adapt" can also work by itself. And here "to" is just part of the infinitive. Imagine replacing the word "adapted" with "changed" and it might be clearer.

Answer (score 2):

To *adapt to process* is to change **in a way that permits** —or, depending on context, **in order to be capable of** —processing, whereas to *adapt to processing* means to change **as a result of** or **through repeated experience with** processing.

A parallel distinction can be seen in the pair

> ***adjust** the valve **to increase** the flow*

and

> ***adjust** building codes **to increasing** hurricane strength*.

A further perspective from which to see the distinction is that the *to* in the former is a particle, whereas the *to* in the latter is a preposition.

Answer (score 1):

This usage (process rather than processing) throws the emphasis back on the subject, so it is the brain itself which has adapted IN ORDER to process information through other senses.

If you say "The brain has adapted to processing ..." that implies that the brain has responded to the processing by adapting, which is a subtly different meaning but important in this context.